# "alternatives" for shared libraries? Does that even work?

Tags: linux, gcc, alternatives

I'm trying to link against a shared library that has several different implementations - specifically blas, openblas and atlas all provide the same binary interface through the `/usr/lib/libblas.so` alternative on Ubuntu 14.04 (and a similar but not identical setup on 12.04). When I use GCC with `-lblas` the linker appears to actually resolve through the alternative link to the actual implementation, so - for example, if I have openblas installed, it will link to the actual openblas binary and if I then install the resulting executable on a system where atlas is installed, the dynamic linker will fail to load the library because it won't see the alternative link.

Is there a way to get GCC to use the "alternative" symbolic link as the dl target so it will actually work as `update-alternatives` intended?

Comment: What does `ldd $your_executable` look like? As far as I understand your explanation, it would not list `libblas.so`, but `libopenblas.so` (or whatever it is called).

Comment: @StefanMajewsky: correct. Specifically `libopenblas` installs `/usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.so.3`, and `ldd` says `libblas.so.3`. Apparently this works in Ubuntu 14.04, more or less as intended, because all other implementations of `libblas.so` also deploy a `libblas.so.3`, just in different directories and in runtime this resolves according to ldconfig order (AFAIU). My problem is that I'm deploying to a different OS where `/usr/lib/libblas.so` alternative resolves to a library file with a different name...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symlink resolution is a feature here. By resolving `libblas.so` to `libblas.so.3`, the resulting executable is pinned to a specific so-version. (Changes to the so-version, i.e. the `3` in `libblas.so.3` occur when the binary interface of the library changes backwards-incompatibly, so this is desired.

The problem seems to be that your target system does not have a `libblas.so.3`, so I recommend the following:

1. Ensure that your application is linked against `libblas.so.3`, as it is already.
2. On the target system, create a symlink from the actual libblas.so to the required `libblas.so.3` name, such that this symlink is found in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

   ```
   mkdir ./mylib
   ln -s /usr/lib/libblas.so ./mylib/libblas.so.3
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD/mylib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./myexecutable
   ```

Comment: Yep, that worked nicely. Thanks. I'm not sure if its a solution anyone can employ (the target machine may not be under the control of the developer), but its a workaround that I can do on my setup.